# jQuery detect when user uses SELECT element in form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, html-select

I want to be able to detect when the user has selected an option from a SELECT element in a form. I know what to do from there, but not sure about how to achieve the initial detection.

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

I would like the solution in JQuery if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *probably* want the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler, like this:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
  var newVal = $(this).val();
  //do something
});
```

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) gets the current value of the dropdown (as a string), just use that to do whatever you want, e.g. `alert("The new value is: " + $(this).val());`, etc.

Comment: Cool thanks. PS... I think you meant "var newVal = $(this).val();"

Comment: I know this is quite late but if you are using the keyboard (tabbing) to navigate a form and use the up/down arrows to choose from a dropdown list then FireFox (22.0) does not trigger the change event. You need to additionally bind keypress for FireFox. Additional Info: jQuery 1.10.2 using the syntax $('select').on('change', function(){ /* do seomthing */ });

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mySelect").bind("change", function(event){ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

or just use

```
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
  //do something here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#mySelect').bind('change',function(e){

        //value of selected item
        var _selectedValues=jQuery(this).val();

        //your codes  here
});
```

i prefer bind over .change(),. click(), etc: as bind is more generic than others.